# How to remove pingback tag xmlrpc from wordperess

Tags: wordpress

whatever plugin I have installed this evil tag always is displayed in the output

```
<link rel="pingback" href="/xmlrpc.php">
```

is there any solution to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution, edit file `wp-includes/general-template.php`

Search for function `rsd_link` and `case 'pingback_url':` and comment the lines referred to xmlrpc

DONE!

Comment: Yeah, and the next time you update WordPress this change will be undone. Not a good idea.

Comment: there isn't a plugin to remove definetly this tag